# How do you tell whether a piece of furniture is veneered?

Tags: wood, furniture, veneer

What are good telltale signs of solid wood vs veneered furniture that you can identify from a picture?

For example, the hutch below?

[image]

Comment: You'll need to rephrase this question to not be a wood identification question.  Those are specifically off-topic for this site.  You should also ideally edit it to be more general.  Nobody gains anything from knowing if the particular piece in your house is solid wood.  On the other hand, "how can I tell solid wood furniture from plywood furniture?" is a good question for this site.

Comment: Edges. Edges are the tell-all giveaway in most veneered pieces. In modern stuff not only does the grain not run continuously from face to edge the edges aren't even always wood because plastic edging is a thing, and once you get used to spotting it it looks hideous and cheap (but isn't always on stuff that *is* cheap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like plywood to me.  It's pretty hard to tell without a better photo, but here's what I'm seeing...

- The panel on the left of the photo appears to be three bookmatched sections, but I can't quite tell if they're close enough to be veneers.
- The front edge of that panel appears to be edge banding, but without a higher resolution image or a shot from underneath the curve (where end-grain would be exposed) it's hard to tell.
- The bullnose profile on the writing surface is applied as a separate piece from the panel.  If this were solid wood you'd just roundover the panel.
- The pulls look like they are separate pieces instead of being carved directly into the panels.

Comment: Thank you! Here's the highest resolution image I have: https://imgur.com/a/sM6qT

Comment: +1 except that one can't be sure it's plywood. Without examining the piece (or seeing a photo of a bare edge) what the substrate is is just a guess. It could have, and if quite recent might even be likely to have, MDF or chipboard/particleboard as the core.

Comment: But definitely not solid wood, right?

Comment: Good point @Graphus.  For that matter, it could even be (particularly if it were older, which it clearly isn't) veneer over a solid wood core of a secondary species.

Comment: @Wynne, yes absolutely no doubt in my mind this is not solid wood.